# Passing a vector as va_list as a function args in C++ 17

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following function that `sprintf` format with a given `vector` list. The vector consist of `uint64_t` with the first index as hex values (`%lx`) always and the rest are decimal (`%d`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>

std::string printVector(const char* format, ...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);

  int size = std::vsnprintf(nullptr, 0, format, args) + 1; // Extra space for '\0'
  std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[size]);
  std::vsnprintf(buf.get(), size, format, args);

  va_end(args);
  return std::string(buf.get());
}

int main() {
  const char* format = "SMEM = %lx smId = %u abId = %u";
  std::vector<uint64_t> vec = {0x1234567890ABCDEF, 2, 4};
  std::string output = printVector(format, vec.data(), vec.size());
  std::cout << output << '\n';
  
  vec = {0x1234567890ABCD01, 6, 5};
  output = printVector(format, vec.data(), vec.size());
  std::cout << output << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

I want to be able to print out like this:

```
SMEM = 0x1234567890ABCDEF smId = 2 abId = 4
SMEM = 0x1234567890ABCD01 smId = 6 abId = 6
```

but im getting this:

```
SMEM = 7fc24b103ec0 smId = 1259401216 abId = 3
SMEM = 0 smId = 1259401216 abId = 374
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Why not using variadic templates in this situation? You could gain type safety.

Comment: `SMEM` values will be coming from C implementation in a header, I hardcode it here as an example. I tried using `std::initializer_list` but it was not working.

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour. Much shorter version of the same: `printf("SMEM = %lx smId = %u abId = %u", vec.data(), vec.size());`. Also, `vsnprintf` "comsumes" `args`; you need to `va_copy` if you want to reuse the argument list.

Comment: You’re not passing the vector contents to the variadic function, you’re only passing the pointer and length of the vector data. There is no way to dynamically build a list of variadic arguments in standard C++.

Comment: @molbdnilo I will continue to use the string in the main and later write it to a file. that's why I created the `printVector`

Comment: That's irrelevant. Your format string and the arguments don't agree, and you can only use an argument list once.

Comment: The VA arguments to the `vsnprintf` should be:  `unsigned long, unsigned int, unsigned int`.  The arguments actually being passed are `uint64_t*, size_t`.  Those don't match.

Comment: The problems in your code are the following: (a) you cannot dynamically build a variadic argument list, you can only do `printVector(format, vec[0], vec[1], vec[2])`; (b) `printVector` consumes the `va_list` twice, you have to declare two, use `va_copy`, and pass each copy to a different invocation of `vsnprintf`; (c) the format string itself should use `PRIx64` and `PRIu64` in `<cinttypes>`; (d) the vector should have probably been a struct anyway; (e) printVector doesn’t pass the allocation size to the `std::string` constructor. I am unsure whether to answer this or close as unfocused.